# Different types of class names in html

Tags: html, visual-studio, html5-canvas, naming-conventions, classname

What is the diff bw

- class="name"
- class="name-new"
- class="name new"
  What is the difference bw the three and is there any other naming convention too?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that in case:

1. `class="name"`: to the element will be applied only the properties of class "name"
2. `class="name-new"`: like point one, but in this case the class is "name-new"
3. `class="name new"`: in this case, to element will be applied two different classe: "name" and "new"

The "space" is used to separete multiple classes, same principle is used for the "id".

Also.. the syntax `class="name-new"` is not equal to use `class="name_new"`.